# Partially executed init.sql

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am setting up a dev environment based on `docker-compose` for a simple tool that needs just a table with a few columns. I can successfully build the image with the followting *docker-compose.yml* file.

```yaml
services:
  # [main service...]

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: feedback_db
    volumes:
      - "./init_db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init_db.sql"
      - "./mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=testing
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=feedback
      - MYSQL_USER=db_user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    restart: on-failure
    network_mode: host

volumes:
  mysql:
```

Using the following `init_db.sql` commands:

```sql
-- create db if missing
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS feedback;

-- create table
USE feedback;

CREATE TABLE user_feedback (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  session_id VARCHAR(250),
  ts TIMESTAMP,
  content VARCHAR(250),
  feedback VARCHAR(250),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Now, everything gets built perrfectly and although the db gets created as per the init commands, the table creation part doesn't gets executed. The command works perfectly when executed manually inside the container.

Comment: Are there any hints in the container logs?  (Note that the `MYSQL_DATABASE` environment variable will also cause the database to be created; it's possible your script isn't running at all.)

Comment: note [the entry point creates MYSQL_DATABASE](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L278) and [uses it as the default database](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L208).  Also suggest `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ....`

Comment: Using volumes is `./mysql:/var/lib/mysql` meant to be `mysql:/var/lib/mysql`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem, writing an answer here as it might be helpful for other people with similar problem.
As @David correctly spotted, `init_db.sql` wasn't getting executed at all as `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` expects to be mapped to a folder and not to a specific file as I was doing.

Putting `init_db.sql` file into a `./ìnit_db` folder gets the job done:

```yaml
mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: feedback_db
    command: mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
      - "./dev/init_db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"  # change: map to folder
      - "./mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=testing
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=feedback
      - MYSQL_USER=db_user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    restart: on-failure
    network_mode: host
```

There's no need to create the database in my `init_db.sql` file as that will be taken care of by `docker-compose`. `init_db.sql` can be reworked into:

```sql
-- create table
USE feedback;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_feedback (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  session_id VARCHAR(250),
  ts TIMESTAMP,
  content VARCHAR(250),
  feedback VARCHAR(250),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```